# trying to pass parameter to subsystem but is outputting tabs

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pass a parameter that enables verbose logging with syslog. Passing -v to the application definitely works as expected. So I am trying to add this option to a json config file.

Here is what I have in the json config:

```
"rtl": {
            "freq": 144.390,
            "ppm": -3,
            "gain": 44.5,
            "debug": true,
            "offset_tuning": false,
            "device_index": 0,
    },
```

Here is what I have in the code. Note: All the other parts work except when I add the -v statement.

```
if self.config['source'] == 'rtl':
   proc_src = subprocess.Popen(
   ['rtl_fm', '-f', str(int(self.config['rtl']['freq'] * 1e6)), '-s', '22050',
   '-v', str(self.config['rtl'].get('debug', 'true')), '-v'],,
   '-p', str(self.config['rtl']['ppm']), '-g', str(self.config['rtl']['gain']),
   '-E', 'offset' if self.config['rtl'].get('offset_tuning', False) else 'none',
   '-d', str(self.config['rtl'].get('device_index', 0)), '-'],
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open('/dev/null')
)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymultimonaprs/multimon.py', 37, 62, "\t\t\t\t\t'-v', str(self.config['rtl'].get('debug', 'true')), '-v'],\n"))
```

It seems like tabs are getting thrown into the -d statement. I'm fairly new to python and just struggling with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two commas:

```
'-v', str(self.config['rtl'].get('debug', 'true')), '-v'],,
                                                         ^^
```

Comment: Now I get:

    SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymultimonaprs/multimon.py', 34, 64, "\t\t\t\t\t'-v', str(self.config['rtl'].get('debug', 'true')), '-v'],,\n"))

Comment: The whole statement seems to have multiple issues: non-matching parenthesis and commas. Please check it or rebuild it again.

Comment: When I take out the -v statement everything works though. I guess I don't see where I have anything that doesn't match in the -v statement. It's basically identical to the -E statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc_src = subprocess.Popen(
   ['rtl_fm', 
    '-f', str(int(self.config['rtl']['freq'] * 1e6)),
  '-s', '22050',
   '-v', str(self.config['rtl'].get('debug', 'true')), 
  '-v', #?
   '-p', str(self.config['rtl']['ppm']), 
   '-g', str(self.config['rtl']['gain']),
   '-E', 'offset' 
   if self.config['rtl'].get('offset_tuning', False) else 'none',
   '-d', str(self.config['rtl'].get('device_index', 0)), '-'
   ],
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open('/dev/null'))
```

Comment: File "/usr/local/bin/pymultimonaprs", line 23, in <module>
    config = json.load(open(args.config))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded